# Cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

Tags: android

Someone please help me....
Cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist in android studio.

Comment: you can get rid of this error by copying the value of compileSdkVersion in the app level build.gradle and pasting it in the compileSdkVersion of your library

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Project Files" view and open the build gradle.

You will find something like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

You have to add this definition:

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
    targetSdkVersion = 21
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just fixed this by remove

`apply plugin: 'android-reporting'`

and everything is ok !